# SwiftでURLから動画の解像度が取得できない

Tags: swift, swift5

Swift5で以下のようなコードを使って、Documentsディレクトリ内に保存した動画の解像度を取得しようとしたのですが、nilが返されてしまいます。何が原因でしょうか？

```
   let resolution = self.resolutionForLocalVideo(url: videoURL)

    private func resolutionForLocalVideo(url: URL) -> CGSize? {
        guard let track = AVURLAsset(url: url).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
        let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
        return CGSize(width: abs(size.width), height: abs(size.height))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コードを試したみたところ解像度を取得するコードには問題ないので、ドキュメントパス(URL)が間違っているのかもしれません。